# MySQL Error: Column 'accountStatus' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this piece of code here and i have the ambiguous error

```
if (Database.Query(ref reader, "SELECT fromID, toID, status, accountStatus, name FROM friends LEFT JOIN phpbb_users ON ( (user_id = toID) OR (user_id = fromID) ) AND (user_id != " + userID + ") WHERE (fromID=" + userID + " OR toID=" + userID + ")") == false)
{
     return null;
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

The optimizer is confused on what table `accountStatus` will it come from since both table contains column name `accountStatus`. To remove ambiguity error, add a table name before the column name in your `SELECT` clause.

Either

```
friends.accountStatus
```

or

```
phpbb_users.accountStatus
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the table name before column name

```
table.accountstatus
```

Answer (score 0):

The ambigous message is probably telling you that your 'accountStatus' column exists in more than one table you are selecting from, so it doesn't know which table to select out of.  Prefix the column names in your select list with the table names.

Answer (score 0):

Both tables contains a column with the same name. You should help the parser to identify which table column you want. A simple way is using an alias

```
"SELECT f.fromID, f.toID, f.status, u.accountStatus, u.name " + 
"FROM friends f LEFT JOIN phpbb_users u ON .......
```